# Different Result when function is called inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS Code which check a webpage to see if new Keys are posted on it at regular interval. Now the problem is that:

- When `start()` is directly called from Dev Console (F12), the results are Correct  and when my Function `$(document).ready` calls it the results are Wrong, and yes i have 100 times confirmed that no content on page is changing.
- I was just curious to see if the vars are getting out of sync, so i called `start()` 2 times in `$(document).ready`, and still the wrong results but when i called `satrt()` from F12 (after calling it 20 times from `$(document).ready`, i got Correct Result.
- I have confirmed that all events are waiting for each other to finsih (maybe called `synchronous`) and its not true that any single statement is running in a different thread.

Then how its possible that if `F12` calls it, then its Correct and if `$(document).ready` calls it then its wrong.

## A intresting point to be noted:

When i didn't had `$(document).ready` in my code, i called `wow()` from `start()` which also gave me wrong result, but F12 gives Correct.
Now that i have `$(document).ready` , if i call `start()` from it which inturn calls `wow()` gives me wrong result, but now if i call `start()` from my console, it gives me right result!

What i acually want to do in simpler form:

1. **wait for page to finish loading**
2. Call `wow()`
3. **wait for `wow()` to finish**
4. Reload Page

Same process continues in infinite loop.

Humble Thanks for any help, this has been wating my time for almost 5-6 hours!

JS Code : http://pastebin.com/9UJYdepU

EDIT:

Correct output:

```
a.js:136 Started
a.js:33 Called Wow
a.js:83 ---------------------KEY 7.0----------------
a.js:83 ---------------------KEY 7.1----------------
a.js:83 ---------------------KEY 7.2----------------
a.js:102 LAST used keys : Saab,Volvo,BMW,4E69G-8GNG4-JCZ4Z,H63HQ-VHWPX-ZCJ8J,FKZGK-MXL5C-P2YTE,4E69G-xxxxxx-JCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JasasCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JasaaaasCZ4Z
a.js:140 WOWO DONW
```

Wrong Output:

```
Started
a.js:33 Called Wow
a.js:102 LAST used keys : Saab,Volvo,BMW,4E69G-8GNG4-JCZ4Z,H63HQ-VHWPX-ZCJ8J,FKZGK-MXL5C-P2YTE,4E69G-xxxxxx-JCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JasasCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JasaaaasCZ4Z
a.js:140 WOWO DONW
```

`document.getElementsByTagName("p");` Gives: http://pastebin.com/JXQ9483N
`localStorage.getItem("usedp")` Gives `Saab,Volvo,BMW,4E69G-8GNG4-JCZ4Z,H63HQ-VHWPX-ZCJ8J,FKZGK-MXL5C-P2YTE,4E69G-xxxxxx-JCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JasasCZ4Z,4E69G-AAAxx-JasaaaasCZ4Z`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved it! This was all becuase of evil Jquery (Sorry, if i hurt you).

$(document).ready was triggering when the page started loading not when it has finsihed loading, my alternate solution is:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ chk() }, 500);
function chk(){

if(document.readyState=="complete"){
        clearInterval(myVar);

    startt();


}
}
```